# Python, iPython Notebook implementation details confusing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am currently working on this: http://cs231n.github.io/assignment1/ . As you can see it is just a very very very very basic exercise in computer vision. But I'm having great difficulty just implementing what is in it. Basically I have this file here: vision.stanford.edu/teaching/cs231n/assignment1.zip and I need to make it run. But within it I found the first lines of code to be confusing:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from cs231n.data_utils import load_CIFAR10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

cs231n.data_utils is not recognized and i don't know to specify the directory for the machine to know. And I don't really understand much about iPython Notebook either, right now I only know how to view it online but I still can't run the code.I'm just a newbie in Python, all I know about the language is that I type several lines into the command lines, and it will do the magic. This seems to be too much. Please help me, thank you very much!

Update: I found a quick&dirty solution: Put the folder into the default directory. But then 2 new errors popped up:

1) First there was this error: in the file data_utils.py there was a line: import cPickle as pickle. And it said: No module named cPickle. I had to change the name from cPickle to _pickle for it to run.
2) These code here:

```
# Load the raw CIFAR-10 data.
cifar10_dir = u'cs231n/datasets/cifar-10-batches-py'
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_CIFAR10(cifar10_dir)

# As a sanity check, we print out the size of the training and test data.
#print ('Training data shape: ', X_train.shape)
# print ('Training labels shape: ', y_train.shape)
# print ('Test data shape: ', X_test.shape)
#print ('Test labels shape: ', y_test.shape)
```

The error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-abf216ad1f9c> in <module>()
      1 # Load the raw CIFAR-10 data.
      2 cifar10_dir = u'cs231n/datasets/cifar-10-batches-py'
----> 3 X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_CIFAR10(cifar10_dir)
      4 
      5 # As a sanity check, we print out the size of the training and test data.

C:\Users\son\assignment1\cs231n\data_utils.py in load_CIFAR10(ROOT)
     20   for b in range(1,6):
     21     f = os.path.join(ROOT, u'data_batch_%d' % (b, ))
---> 22     X, Y = load_CIFAR_batch(f)
     23     xs.append(X)
     24     ys.append(Y)

C:\Users\son\assignment1\cs231n\data_utils.py in load_CIFAR_batch(filename)
      7   """ load single batch of cifar """
      8   with open(filename.encode('utf-8'), u'rb') as f:
----> 9     datadict = pickle.load(f)
     10     X = datadict[u'data']
     11     Y = datadict[u'labels']

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And here is the data_utils file:

```
# import cPickle as pickle
import _pickle as pickle
import numpy as np
import os

def load_CIFAR_batch(filename):
  """ load single batch of cifar """
  with open(filename, u'rb') as f:
    datadict = pickle.load(f)
    X = datadict[u'data']
    Y = datadict[u'labels']
    X = X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype(u"float")
    Y = np.array(Y)
    return X, Y

def load_CIFAR10(ROOT):
  """ load all of cifar """
  xs = []
  ys = []
  for b in range(1,6):
    f = os.path.join(ROOT, u'data_batch_%d' % (b, ))
    X, Y = load_CIFAR_batch(f)
    xs.append(X)
    ys.append(Y)   
  Xtr = np.concatenate(xs)
  Ytr = np.concatenate(ys)
  del X, Y
  Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR_batch(os.path.join(ROOT, u'test_batch'))
  return Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to python, you're jumping into the deep end with this assignment-- python has a gentle learning curve if you start right.

Before you get coding you should get set up and acquainted with notebooks. See [here](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) to get started. Installing the dependencies is a bear (or used to), so I recommend downloading the Anaconda Scientific Python distribution, which includes everything you need.

For importing the `cs231n` module, the quickest solution is to just put the folder `cs231n` in the folder that contains your notebook (or your .py script). Later you can google `PYTHONPATH` and set it up at your convenience.

Good luck with it!

PS. I just looked at your course folder and it looks like your instructor has taken care of dependencies! If you followed directions and it didn't work, contact him or her.

Comment: I have googled PYTHONPATH, and I followed one of their advices: Set up an enviromental variable, name it PYTHONPATH, and specify its directory to the cs231 folder. And when I ran again, it did find the directory, but it produced yet another weird error: import cPickle as pickle; ImportError: No module named ' cPickle'. I'm confused

Comment: The error you're reporting would happen if you are using python 3, but are trying to import code written for python 2. This would account for a lot of weird errors. Sounds like you need to ditch your python and install 2.7 (ugh), preferably in a virtualenv as advised.

Comment: And did you study your instructor's directions? They look like they're designed to set everything up for you.

Comment: actually I'm using anaconda right now, but I think they have the 2.7 version. And I'm trying to follow the site's instructions but it seeems to be very weird,

Comment: You are taking a class with instructors and TAs whose job is to help you out. Bring in your laptop and ask someone to walk you through it-- it'll do you a lot more good than asking us random strangers here to guess what might be going wrong with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the two errors are all about compatibility of python. This assignment code is write in python2.7,  I wonder if you are using python3?  If you are, you'd better change to python2.7 .

By the way, it is a really late answer.